# Spring JMS - Mock send and receive using two different message converters

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, jms, spring-jms

I have a Spring application that is listening to a service bus topic for a payload of type say ClassA. This service updates the repository and creates a new status update object of type say ClassB and then sends it to a different service bus topic.

I want to write a integration test to test this service however I am facing an error as I am using a custom Messaging Converter while sending the message however the same converter does not work when receiving the message as the payload type is different.

Can someone please help?

I tried creating multiple JmsMessagingTemplate beans with their own messaging converters but I am still getting an error in object conversion.